# How to create a synonym for a table in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, database-migration, synonym

I am migrating this Oracle command to PostgreSQL:

```
CREATE SYNONYM &user..emp FOR &schema..emp;
```

Please suggest to me how I can migrate the above command.

Comment: Relevant?: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45238572/synonym-support-on-postgresql

Comment: Ways to set the `search_path`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9067777/939860

Answer (score 3):

You don't need synonyms.

There are two approaches:

1. using the schema search path:

   ```
   ALTER DATABASE xyz SET search_path = schema1, schema2, ...;
   ```

   Put the schema that holds the table on the `search_path` of the database (or user), then it can be used without schema qualification.
2. using a view:

   ```
   CREATE VIEW dest_schema.tab AS SELECT * FROM source_schema.tab;
   ```

The first approach is good if you have a lot of synonyms for objects in the same schema.

Comment: GRANT CREATE,USAGE ON SCHEMA schemaname TO username;
alter ROLE username set search_path=schemaname;

Comment: I want to create synonyms for some tables from the schema.If i did like above it will create for all the tables from schema right?

Comment: so I can use second approach (creating the view) right?

Comment: The second approach is quite fine. I don't understand why Oracle created synonyms in the first place...

Answer (score 3):

PostgreSQL does not support SYNOSYM or ALIAS. Synonym is a non SQL 2003 feature implemented by Microsoft SQL 2005 (I think). While it does provide an interesting abstraction, but due to lack of relational integrity, it can be considered a risk.

That is, you can create a synonym, advertise it to you programmers, the code is written around it, including stored procedures, then one day the backend of this synonym (or link or pointer) is changed/deleted/etc leading to a run time error. I don't even think a prepare would catch that.

It is the same trap as the symbolic links in unix and null pointers in C/C++.

But rather create a DB view and it is already updateable as long as it contains one table select only.

```
CREATE VIEW schema_name.synonym_name AS SELECT * FROM schema_name.table_name;
```

Comment: Also supported by Oracle since 2001. If a feature exists in the top two database systems in the world for two decades, it's probably a good feature.

Comment: The abstraction of synonyms represents a risk (but no more than the risk of renaming a table) but that risk enables abstraction. That is it to say you provide developers options of  re-pointing a synonym to a different table during maintenance and rollouts of new features. Developers have come to depend on synonyms to enable smoother rollouts.